# How to use chrome.storage api to store data(url,timestamp) from these 2 eventlisteners defined in background.js file of my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**background.js**

i want to store the values(change.url, d.toISOString()) in the local storage using **chrome.storage.local.set()**.

I don't know how to define this storage function in my eventListeners

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId,change,tab) => {
   if(change.url){
    console.log(change.url);
    var d=new Date();
    console.log(d.toISOString());
    
    //console.log(tab);
   }
});


chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  // how to fetch tab url using activeInfo.tabid
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
     console.log(tab.url);
     var d1=new Date();
     console.log(d1.toISOString());
     
  });
});
```

Comment: There's no need to define it. Just add it to `permissions` and call it as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: Thanks!! I created JSON objects and pushed items, now looking how to connect database to local chrome storage